# How to replace blanks for groups of columns based on column group prefix?

Tags: r, replace, na, prefix

How do I replace NA's in a column with all 0's based on if a value exists in other columns that begin with the same prefix? For example, for column A1, I only want to replace the NA's with a 0 where columns A2 or A3 are NONBLANK. My real data has hundreds of groups of columns.

**MY DATA:**

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
A1<-c(1,NA,1,NA,1,1,1,NA)
A2<-c(1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA)
A3<-c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA)
B1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,1)
B2<-c(1,1,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA)
B3<-c(1,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA)

mydata<-cbind.data.frame(ID,A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3)
```

**HAVE:**

[image]

**WANTED:**

A 0 should replace NA in column A1 if column A2 or A3 have a 1. A 0 should replace NA in column A2 if columns A1 or A3 have a 1, and so on, as below:
[image]

Comment: Partial answer because I have to run off to a meeting, but you can index non-missing values in A1 and A2 with: mydata[!is.na(mydata[c('A1','A2')])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-refined answer in base `R`, but seems to work:

```
for(i in unique(gsub("\\d","",colnames(mydata)[-1]))){
  mydata[apply(mydata[,grepl(i,colnames(mydata))],1,function(x) any(!is.na(x))),grepl(i,colnames(mydata))][is.na(mydata[apply(mydata[,grepl(i,colnames(mydata))],1,function(x) any(!is.na(x))),grepl(i,colnames(mydata))])]<-0
}
```

Which gives:

```
  ID A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  2 NA NA NA  1  1  1
3  3  1  0  0  1  1  0
4  4  0  1  0  1  1  0
5  5  1  0  1  1  0  1
6  6  1  1  0  1  1  0
7  7  1  0  0 NA NA NA
8  8 NA NA NA  1  0  0
```

**Edit:**
The idea is to extract the `unique` letters from `colnames(mydata)`, `A` and `B` in the example, by replacing the digits (`\\d`) with a blank `""`.
It then loop over these letters to select the columns that start with it. That's what `grepl(i,colnames(mydata))` does.
`apply` is used to get a vector of the rows in which there is at least (`any()`) one non-NA value (`!is.na()`) : `apply(mydata[,grepl(i,colnames(mydata))],1,function(x) any(!is.na(x)))`.
Everything is then combined in what it essentially `df[is.na(df))]<-0` but with `df` corresponding to the columns strating with the given letter, and the rows that should have `NA`'s replaced.
`df` would be : `mydata[apply(mydata[,grepl(i,colnames(mydata))],1,function(x) any(!is.na(x))),grepl(i,colnames(mydata))]`

Comment: You should edit in some horizontal and vertical whitespace to make this more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Another method is

```
mydata[, 2:4][is.na(mydata[, 2:4])] <- rep(NA^(rowSums(is.na(mydata[2:4])) == 3) - 1,
                                           length(2:4))[is.na(mydata[, 2:4])]
mydata[, 5:7][is.na(mydata[, 5:7])] <- rep(NA^(rowSums(is.na(mydata[5:7])) == 3) - 1,
                                           length(5:7))[is.na(mydata[, 5:7])]

mydata
  ID A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  2 NA NA NA  1  1  1
3  3  1  0  0  1  1  0
4  4  0  1  0  1  1  0
5  5  1  0  1  1  0  1
6  6  1  1  0  1  1  0
7  7  1  0  0 NA NA NA
8  8 NA NA NA  1  0  0
```

---

The column values are hard-coded, which is not helpful with many groups, so following @haboryme's technique, you could do

```
# group columns into list elements with lapply and grep
myCols <- lapply(c("A", "B"), function(i) grep(i, colnames(mydata)))

# loop through and make changes
for(i in myCols) {
  mydata[, i][is.na(mydata[, i])] <- rep(NA^(rowSums(is.na(mydata[i])) == 3) - 1,
                                         length(i))[is.na(mydata[, i])]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

a customised function using `lapply()`: generalised to have any number of columns provided they follow this pattern of having single alphabets

```
func <- function(x){
  df <- mydata[grepl(x, colnames(mydata))] # extract only the same letter columns
  m <- !is.na(df)          # create a logical matrix to know which all are NA's
  i = which(rowSums(m)!=0) # if all had NA's then summ will be 0. so avoid that
  df[i,][is.na(df[i,])] <- 0 # insert wherever NA's to be 0( but only in those rows decided above)
  return(df)
  }

data.frame(ID = mydata$ID,lapply(LETTERS[1:2], func))
#  ID A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
#1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#2  2 NA NA NA  1  1  1
#3  3  1  0  0  1  1  0
#4  4  0  1  0  1  1  0
#5  5  1  0  1  1  0  1
#6  6  1  1  0  1  1  0
#7  7  1  0  0 NA NA NA
#8  8 NA NA NA  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Two tidyverse options; which is more practical depends on the dimensions of your actual data. Both leverage `coalesce` conditionally.

Manually:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>% rowwise() %>%    # group by row
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('A')),    # for A prefixes, coalesce if not all NA
              funs(ifelse(all(is.na(c(A1, A2, A3))), ., coalesce(., 0)))) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('B')),    # likewise for B
              funs(ifelse(all(is.na(c(B1, B2, B3))), ., coalesce(., 0))))

## Source: local data frame [8 x 7]
## Groups: <by row>
## 
## # A tibble: 8 × 7
##      ID    A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
## 2     2    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1
## 3     3     1     0     0     1     1     0
## 4     4     0     1     0     1     1     0
## 5     5     1     0     1     1     0     1
## 6     6     1     1     0     1     1     0
## 7     7     1     0     0    NA    NA    NA
## 8     8    NA    NA    NA     1     0     0
```

or programmatically, with reshaping:

```
mydata %>% gather(var, val, -ID) %>%    # reshape to long
    group_by(ID, letter = substr(var, 1, 1)) %>%    # group by ID and prefix
    mutate(val = if(all(is.na(val))) val else coalesce(val, 0)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% select(-letter) %>% spread(var, val)    # clean up

## # A tibble: 8 × 7
##      ID    A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
## * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
## 2     2    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1
## 3     3     1     0     0     1     1     0
## 4     4     0     1     0     1     1     0
## 5     5     1     0     1     1     0     1
## 6     6     1     1     0     1     1     0
## 7     7     1     0     0    NA    NA    NA
## 8     8    NA    NA    NA     1     0     0
```

If prefixes can extend beyond a single letter, replace `substr` with a suitable regex, e.g. `sub('\\d+$', '', var)`.